# PostgreSQL is ignoring my composite index

Tags: postgresql, indexing

Here is the table in question and its indexes. This table in production contains ~ 50 million rows.

```
    CREATE TABLE "public"."audit_page_loads" (
    "id" int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('audit_page_loads_id_seq'::regclass),
    "dt" timestamp(6) NULL,
    "ip" varchar(255) COLLATE "default",
    "method" varchar(255) COLLATE "default",
    "action" varchar(255) COLLATE "default",
    "elapsed" numeric(8,2) DEFAULT 0,
    "views" numeric(8,2) DEFAULT 0,
    "db" numeric(8,2) DEFAULT 0
)
WITH (OIDS=FALSE);
ALTER TABLE "public"."audit_page_loads" ADD PRIMARY KEY ("id") NOT DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE;

CREATE INDEX  "index_audit_page_loads_on_action" ON "public"."audit_page_loads" USING btree("action" COLLATE "default" ASC NULLS LAST);
CREATE INDEX  "index_audit_page_loads_on_action_and_dt" ON "public"."audit_page_loads" USING btree("action" COLLATE "default" ASC NULLS LAST, dt ASC NULLS LAST);
```

When I run this select against the table it takes close to a minute to return results. I was assuming that since I have a composite index on action and dt, that would cause my select to do index scans. Not so. Each query is a sequence scan

```
SELECT action, avg(elapsed), count(*) 
FROM audit_page_loads 
WHERE action != 'UsersController#login' and dt >= '2014-09-01'
GROUP BY action

Limit  (cost=1685321.43..1685321.68 rows=20 width=32) (actual time=15900.954..15900.968 rows=20 loops=1)
  ->  HashAggregate  (cost=1685321.43..1685321.80 rows=30 width=32) (actual time=15900.952..15900.965 rows=20 loops=1)
        ->  Seq Scan on audit_page_loads  (cost=0.00..1646329.70 rows=5198897 width=32) (actual time=7.075..11826.963 rows=5820401 loops=1)
              Filter: (((action)::text <> 'UsersController#login'::text) AND (dt >= '2014-09-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
              Rows Removed by Filter: 52614815
Total runtime: 15901.013 ms
```

When I add ***set enable_seqscan=false;*** to that select, the results are instantaneous. .13 seconds and I can see in the explain that the "index_audit_page_loads_on_action_and_dt" index is used. Why do I have to force that? And if I understand correctly, including that ***set enable_seqscan=false;*** is not advisable. Can someone help me here?

***PostgreSQL 9.3.5 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3, 64-bit***

Comment: Edit your question, and paste the results of `explain analyze SELECT action...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your WHERE clause isn't [sargable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable). But there might be an equivalent expression that *is* sargable.

I built your table, and loaded about a million rows of randomish data.

```
explain analyze
select action, avg(elapsed), count(*) 
from audit_page_loads 
where action < 'UsersController#login' and dt >= '2014-09-01'
   or action > 'UsersController#login' and dt >= '2014-09-01'
group by action;
```

```
"HashAggregate  (cost=75.45..75.46 rows=1 width=24) (actual time=0.379..0.379 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on audit_page_loads  (cost=9.20..75.32 rows=17 width=24) (actual time=0.264..0.276 rows=90 loops=1)"
"        Recheck Cond: ((((action)::text = '2014-09-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)) OR (((action)::text > 'UsersController#login'::text) AND (dt >= '2014-09-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)))"
"        ->  BitmapOr  (cost=9.20..9.20 rows=17 width=0) (actual time=0.259..0.259 rows=0 loops=1)"
"              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on audit_page_loads_action_dt_idx  (cost=0.00..4.59 rows=8 width=0) (actual time=0.191..0.191 rows=90 loops=1)"
"                    Index Cond: (((action)::text = '2014-09-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))"
"              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on audit_page_loads_action_dt_idx  (cost=0.00..4.59 rows=8 width=0) (actual time=0.067..0.067 rows=0 loops=1)"
"                    Index Cond: (((action)::text > 'UsersController#login'::text) AND (dt >= '2014-09-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))"
"Total runtime: 0.431 ms"
```

On my box, this reduced the run time from about 186 ms to about 0.4 ms. YMMV; I'm sure my data doesn't look quite like yours.

In the general case, whether you can replace a nonsargable operator with an equivalent sargable predicate in a WHERE clause depends on the data type, on collation order, and on case sensitivity. Test with your own data.

Answer (score 2):

Indexes on `action` cannot be used here as you're using `!=` comparison for `action` column. It is not possible to get use of index if you're looking for values outside it.

Instead, you could try the following:

```
CREATE INDEX i_1 ON audit_page_loads(dt);
```

If your predicate `action != 'UsersController#login'` is used quite often, you can try creating partial index:

```
CREATE INDEX i_1 ON audit_page_loads(dt) WHERE action != 'UsersController#login';
```

According to the `Rows Removed by Filter: 52614815` entry from your plan, this index should quite good one.

As you're using a range lookup on the `dt` column in your query, it's not possible to optimize also the `GROUP BY` to use indexes, so you'll have the `HashAgg` node. But with the index, time should be much better now.